# How to solve following linear differential-difference equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, delay-differential-equations

How to solve following linear differential-difference equation?

$$\frac{da_{n}(t)}{dt}=i k na_{n}(t)+G\left\{n(n-1)a_{n-2}(t)-a_{n+2}(t) \right\},~n=0,1,2,\ldots~~~~~(1)$$

where, k and G is a constant. And $i$ is the imaginary unit. The initial conditions are 
$$a_{n}(0)=\delta_{mn}=\begin{cases}
C_{0}~~(n=m)
\\
0~~(n\neq m)
\end{cases}$$ where, $C_{0}$ is a constant.
$a_{0}(t)$ and $a_{1}(t)$ is unknown function. I want to find $a_{n}(t)$.

If $k=0$, then equation $(1)$ reduce to following equation:
$$
\frac{da_{n}(t)}{dt}=G\left\{n(n-1)a_{n-2}(t)-a_{n+2}(t) \right\},~n=0,1,2,\ldots.~~~~~(\mathrm{A})
$$

The general solution of equation $(\mathrm{A})$ is
$$
a_{n}(t)=C_{0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\mathstrut 2\pi}}\left(\frac{n}{2} \right)!~\sqrt[]{\mathstrut 2^{n}}\left\{1+(-1)^{n+1} \right\}(\cosh{2Gt})^{-\frac{3}{2}}(\tanh{2Gt})^{-\frac{1}{2}(n-1)}.~~~~~(\mathrm{B})
$$
Equation $(\mathrm{B})$ satisfy following initial conditions:
$$
a_{n}(0)=\begin{cases}
C_{0}~~(n=1)
\\
0~~~~~(n\neq 1)
\end{cases}
~~~~~~~~~(\mathrm{C})
$$

I have tried Laplace transform to equaton $(1)$.

Multiplying both sides of equation $(1)$ by $\mathrm{e}^{-st}$ and then Integrating  for the interval $0$ to $\infty$  to obtain
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}dt~\mathrm{e}^{-st}
\frac{da_{n}(t)}{dt}=i k n\int_{0}^{\infty}dt~\mathrm{e}^{-st}a_{n}(t)+G\left\{n(n-1)\int_{0}^{\infty}dt~\mathrm{e}^{-st}a_{n-2}(t)-\int_{0}^{\infty}dt~\mathrm{e}^{-st}a_{n+2}(t) \right\}.~~~~~(2)
$$

We define the $U_{n}(s)$
$$
U_{n}(s):=\int_{0}^{\infty}dt~\mathrm{e}^{-st}a_{n}(t).~~~~~(3)
$$
Then equation $(2)$ to be
$$
sU_{n}(s)-a_{n}(0)=iknU_{n}(s)+
G\left\{n(n-1)U_{n-2}(s)-U_{n+2}(s) \right\}.~~~~~(4)
$$
where, we use following integration by parts
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}dt~\mathrm{e}^{-st}\frac{d a_{n}(t)}{dt}=sU_{n}(s)-a_{n}(0).
$$

Let's solve equation $(4)$ by using Z-transform.

First, we define unilateral Z-transform $W(s,z)$ as follows:

$$
\mathcal{Z}[U_{n}(s)]=
W(s,z):=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} U_{n}(s)z^{-n}.~~~~~(5)
$$

Noting following relations

Differentiation & Time delay 
$$
\mathcal{Z}[n(n-1)U_{n-2}(s)]=
2z^{-2}W(s,z)-2z^{-1}\frac{\partial W(s,z)}{\partial z}+\frac{\partial^{2}W(s,z)}{\partial z^{2}},
~~~~~~~~(6)
$$
Time advance 
$$
\mathcal{Z}[U_{n+2}(s)]=z^{2}W(s,z)-z^{2}U_{0}(s)-zU_{1}(s),
~~~~~~~~~(7)
$$
Using propaty of $a_{n}(0)=\delta_{mn}$
$$
\mathcal{Z}[a_{n}(0)]=C_{0}z^{-m},
~~~~~~~~~~(8)
$$

we can transform equation $(4)$ as follows: 
$$
Gz^{2}\frac{\partial^{2}W(s,z)}{\partial z^{2}}+(-2G-ikz^{2})z\frac{\partial W(s,z)}{\partial z}
+\left\{z^{2}(-Gz^{2}-s)+2G \right\}W(s,z)+Gz^{3}\left\{zU_{0}(s)+U_{1}(s) \right\} +C_{0}z^{-m+2}=0.
~~~~~~(9)
$$
Equation $(9)$ is some kind of Bessel equation.

I'm trying to solve equation $(9)$.

Comment: Is $i$ there supposed to be the imaginary unit? maybe $ik$ can be replaced by ca constant $c$?

Comment: i is the imaginary unit. I have tried Laplace transform. Then, I have obtained equation $(4)$.

Comment: Define the Z transform of $U_n(s)$ as something like $W(s,z)$, then note the Time Advance and differentiation [properties of the Z transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform). You should obtain a new differential equation over the $z$ variable, with $s$ being a parameter.

Comment: Before find some kind of Bessel equation, I can't transform equation $(6)$.

Comment: I was guessing that equation (9) would be a bessel equation, but apparently I was wrong.

Comment: I'm not aware of a general method to solve equation (9). But if I may suggest one next possible step, the Z transform can be undone with complex integration. Perhaps some clever usage of [Cauchy's Integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) can help you get rid of the derivatives. Another approach would be starting by trying to find a solution to the homogeneous equation, so that you don't have to deal right away with $U_0(s)$ and $U_1(s)$, but you might handle it later.

Comment: For full disclosure, I've never seen a similar problem anywhere, I'm giving hints based on tools I know, but unless this is some homework problem, there is no guarantee that there might exist known method to address this problem, though I doubt this would be an open problem in research level mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

If:
$$
\mathcal{Z}[U_{n}(s)]=
W(s,z):=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} U_{n}(s)z^{-n}
$$

Then:

$$
\mathcal{Z}[U_{n-2}(s)]=
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} U_{n-2}(s)z^{-n}=z^{-2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} U_{n-2}(s)z^{-(n-2)}=z^{-2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} U_{n-2}(s)z^{-(n-2)}
$$

Now because $a_{n-1}=0$ and $a_{n-2}0$ (please check this assumption)
$$
\mathcal{Z}[U_{n-2}(s)]=
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} U_{n-2}(s)z^{-n}=z^{-2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} U_{n-2}(s)z^{-(n-2)}=z^{-2}\mathcal{Z}[U_{n}(s)] = z^{-2}W(s,z) = \Gamma(s,z)
$$
And this is the time-shift property. I'll call the result $\Gamma$ because it will soon be convenient. Then:
$$
\gamma(s,n) =U_{n-2}(s) 
$$

Now look at
$$
\mathcal{Z}[n(n-1)U_{n-2}(s)]=\mathcal{Z}[n(n-1)\gamma(s,n)] =\mathcal{Z}[n^2\gamma(s,n)]- \mathcal{Z}[n\gamma(s,n)]
$$

From the [differentiation property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform):
$$
\mathcal{Z}[n\gamma(s,n)] = -\frac{d}{dz} \left[ \Gamma(s,z)\right] =-\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left[ \Gamma(s,z)\right] =-\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left[ z^{-2}W(s,z)\right] =\\ 2z^{-3}W(s,z)-z^{-2}\frac{\partial W(s,z)}{\partial z}
$$

Now do it again to get  $\mathcal{Z}[n^2\gamma(s,n)] $. Then rebuild your equation 6.

Comment: I can transform equation $(6)$ by using the relation $\mathcal{Z}[n^2 \gamma (s,n)]=z^{2}\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial z^{2}}[\Gamma (s,z)]+z\frac{\partial}{\partial z}[\Gamma[s,z]]=4z^{-2}W(s,z)-3z^{-1}\frac{\partial W(s,z)}{\partial z}+\frac{\partial^{2}W(s,z)}{\partial z^{2}}$

Comment: No, that won't work! Try calling $n\gamma(s,n)= \lambda(s,n)$, then by the procedure I"ve used above you have the transform $\Lambda(s,z)$, but you need to compute the transform $\mathcal{Z}[n\lambda] = -\frac{\partial \Lambda}{\partial z}$

Comment: Is there $\mathcal{Z}[n\gamma (s,n)]=-z\frac{d}{dz}[\Gamma(s,z)]$?

Comment: if $\mathcal{z}[\gamma(s,n)]=\Gamma(s,z)$ then by the Differentiation property of the Z transform we have $\mathcal{z}[n\gamma(s,n)]=-\frac{\partial\Gamma(s,z)}{\partial z}$. Check the [wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform)